# Compare 2 set of 3D cloud points

Tags: python, optimization, lidar, pdal

I am working on the classification of a 3D point cloud using several python libraries (whitebox, PCL, PDAL). My goal is to classify the soil. The data set has been classified by a company so I am based on their classification as ground truth.

For the moment I am able to classify the soil, to do that I declassified the data set and redo a classification with PDAL. Now I'm at the stage of comparing the two datasets to see the quality of my classification.

I made a script which takes the XYZ coordinates of the 2 sets and puts it in a list and I compare them one by one, however the dataset contains around 5 millions points and it takes 1 minute by 5 points at the begining. After few minutes everything crash. Can anyone give me tips? Here a picture of my clouds [The set at the lets is the ground truth and at the right is the one classified by me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgxXc.png)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Would it be possible to include the images within your question rather than providing a link? That way if the URL becomes inactive the images will remain on this site.

Comment: i need at least 10 recomandation before that … so for the moment it's not possible

Comment: You should be at 10+ now.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not using any spatial data structure to ease your point proximity queries. There are several ways you can mitigate this issue, such as [KD tree](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_kd_tree.html) and [Octree](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/group__octree.html).

By using such spatial structures you will be able to discard a large portion of unnecessary distance computations, thus improving the performance.

Comment: Ok great i will try to use this methods !